# How can I mount an EXT4 USB drive on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, usb-storage, ext4

I have a USB drive formatted as [EXT4](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page). How can I mount it in Windows 8?

Ideas on other workarounds are appreciated as well!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you will have to use 3rd party tools to access EXT4 file system on windows 8.Some options include :

- Ext2Fsd
- DiskInternals Linux Reader
- Ext2explore

you may find more info here - http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/

HTH

Comment: Are you sure they work with Widnows 8 ? Ext2Fsd is known to work with windows 8

Comment: Ext2explore I have checked and it worked

Comment: Don't forget to run the installer in Compatibility mode and then run the app as Admin and it should work without issue on Windows 8

Comment: I tried Ext2explore in Windows 8.1, it does work for some partitions, but it doesn't see all partitions in my external disk.

Answer (score 7):

You can try out [Ext2Read](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/), it seemingly works with 8.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't detect partitions on my external USB disk in Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

Try Paragon ExtFS for Windows, it's free for personal use:

http://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-windows/download.html

Comment: It's not free, even for personal use.

Comment: And can it reliably write? Or just read?